# How to get and set RTC time(hwtime) from android native service?

Tags: android, native, real-time-clock

I'm trying to make android native service that can read and set RTC time(hwtime). How can I make this native service get access to RTC time data?

I literally have no clue to implement function for setting rtc time.
Please help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.